# Swift - Multiplying each Element of an Array by 2

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to multiply each element of my code by 2. Here is my code:

```
var arr = [5, 77, 34, -22]

for x in arr {

    arr[arr.index(of: x)!] = x * 2

}

print(arr)
```

This prints the following on the console:

```
[10, 154, 68, -44]
```

When I add 1 to the array, I have the following code:

```
var arr = [5, 77, 34, -22, 1]

for x in arr {

    arr[arr.index(of: x)!] = x * 2

}

print(arr)
```

As expected, the result is the following:

```
[10, 154, 68, -44, 2]
```

However, when I add 2 to the array using the following code:

```
var arr = [5, 77, 34, -22, 1, 2]

for x in arr {

    arr[arr.index(of: x)!] = x * 2

}

print(arr)
```

I get a bizarre result:

```
[10, 154, 68, -44, 4, 2]
```

Why is this the case? I used Playground for all these results. Any explanation would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: [`index(of:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1689674-index) finds the *first* occurrence of the element. The first occurrence of `2` is the element where you doubled the `1`, and *not* the `2` at the end of the array. It would be helpful if you could explain which part of the documentation of `index(of:)` is unclear to you, so that the Swift developers can improve the documentation for future readers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the above way of multiplying element is not a good idea.

**Why?**

because if the number is repeated you will apply the multiplication operation to the element which comes first.

```
 var arr = [1, 2] // result will be [4, 2] 

 // This not expected, you need
 [2, 4]
```

This is what happens in your case. Here is the STDOUT of array for each iteration

```
[5, 77, 34, -22, 1, 2]
[10, 77, 34, -22, 1, 2]
[10, 154, 34, -22, 1, 2]
[10, 154, 68, -22, 1, 2]
[10, 154, 68, -44, 1, 2]
[10, 154, 68, -44, 2, 2]
[10, 154, 68, -44, 4, 2]
```

In the second last state of the array, you can see you got two consecutive `2` and when you call `index: of` it return the index of the first element it finds in sequence.

A better way to do this would be by using `enumration` or `map`.

```
  for (index, value) in arr.enumerated() {
    arr[index] = value * 2
  }

  // or
  let array = arr.map {$0 * 2}
```

Comment: Your explanation makes perfect sense. Thank you so much for this. However, when I copy and paste your code onto Playground, I get the following error in line 1 [of your code]: Expression type '[Int]' is ambiguous without more context. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

#### Alternative for the special case of multiplication by 2 (or powers of it): bitwise left shift `<<`

Since integers are stored in binary format, a multiplication by 2 (the base of binary) is equivalent to a single bitwise left shift `<<` applied to each number.

```
var arr = [5, 77, 34, -22, 1]
arr = arr.map{ $0 << 1 }
print(arr) // [10, 154, 68, -44, 2]
```

I would suspect that this approach have a better performance than the explicit multiplication by 2 (as shown in the other answers), but at the cost of readability/semantics/intent. Unless you're working on a HPC application, the latter should be valued, and the explicit multiplication preferred.

---

**A note on value overflow**

It's worth noting that for a value that is too large to safely enter the multiplication operation (say `value > Int.max / 2`), the explicit multiplication by 2 will yield a value overflow, yielding a runtime exception if the `*` operator is used

```
var arr = [5, 77, 34, -22, Int.max]
arr = arr.map{ $0 * 2 } // runtime exception
```

Whereas the bitwise left shift approach above will avoid the runtime exception by silently discarding any overflow that occurs during the operation

```
var arr = [5, 77, 34, -22, Int.max]
arr = arr.map{ $0 << 1 }
print(arr) // [10, 154, 68, -44, -2]
```

The same discarding is used also when using the masking multiplication operator (`&*`) for the multiplication:

```
var arr = [5, 77, 34, -22, Int.max]
arr = arr.map{ $0 &* 2 }
print(arr) // [10, 154, 68, -44, -2]
```

To understand how the bitwise truncation/overflow discarding ends up in value `-2` for a signed type as `Int`, it's easier to study a smaller type, say `Int8`, in which case the discarding of the overflow becomes apparrent.

```
var arr: [Int8] = [5, 77, 34, -22, Int8.max] // allowed values: -128...127
arr = arr.map{ $0 << 1 }
print(arr) // [10, 154, 68, -44, -2]
    // Int8.max      = 127,  0b1111_1111 (unsigned)
    // Int8.min      = -128, 0b0000_0000 (unsigned)
    // Int8.max << 2 = 0b1111_1111 << 1 = { discard overflow } 
    //               = 0b1111_1110 = -2 (unsigned)

print(Int8(bitPattern: 0b1111_1110)) // -2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr: [Int] = [5, 77, 34, -22, 1, 2]

for x in arr {
    let i = arr.index(of: x)!
    print(i)
    arr[i] = x * 2
}
```

You have this issue because you re-write arr on a each iteration of for in loop. 
That's why, when you came on last iteration step(`arr.index(of: 2)!`), you array has next view: `[10, 154, 68, -44, 2, 2]`.

According to documentation `arr.index(of: x)!` `returns the first index where the specified value appears in the collection.`, so for last step `i` will be `4`, not `5`

Comment: Your explanation makes sense. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `for` loop, you can use `map` method on array.

```
    var arr = [5, 77, 34, -22, 1, 2]
    arr = arr.map {
        return $0 * 2
    }
    print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[10, 154, 68, -44, 2, 4]
```

For more on `map` method refer to: https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/dictionary/1689397-map

Comment: Your explanation makes sense. Thank you for this.